# Using Module32First to get a module's modBaseAddr returns nothing

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get a process module's base address so I can start searching through its memory for certain values.  I'm using Module32First to get the first module and then printing the baseaddr out from a MODULEENTRY32, but nothing appears.

I am targeting another process that I wrote, it simply prints out a few things.  I am able to successfully get a handle to it as well as a snapshot handle. Both processes are 32 bit.  I tried printing out other members of the MODULEENTRY32 such as th32ProcessID and modBaseSize, all of which do return values.  Only modBaseAddr is empty.

I've been looking through the documentation and it must be something wrong with my code.  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
std::cout << "Modules Base Address: " << modStruc.modBaseAddr << std::endl;
```

I expect to print out the first module's base address, but the actual output is empty (as in nothing is displayed).  My understanding of Module32First is that it copies the first module entry to my MODULEENTRY32 modStruc, and after that I print out the modBaseAddr member of it.

Update for anyone with similar issues:  I haven't found a solution to my particular dilemma, but I've since switched to using GetModuleInformation which also gives a module load address, entry point, and size.

Comment: `modBaseAddr` can't be empty. Do you mean it is null instead? Also, is your calling process 32bit or 64bit, and is the target process 32bit or 64bit? Also, you are leaking `currentH` and `currentSnap` in most code branches. You must close open handles when you are done using them.

Comment: If it was NULL and you were printing an address, then you'd see zero. Consider learning to use a debugger.

Comment: `modBaseAddr` was printing empty and wasn't null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MODULEENTRY32::modBaseAddr` is a `BYTE*` which is actually `unsigned char*`.

`std::cout::operator<<` has an overload for `unsigned char*` which will try to print it as a string.

To print the actual address you need to cast it to an integer type, for example:

```
std::cout << "Modules Base Address: " << reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(modStruc.modBaseAddr) << std::endl;
```

You can see an example of this in action [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fb02365dc74fb27).

Comment: Or better, cast it to `void*` so it prints as a pointer and not as an integer: `std::cout << "Modules Base Address: " << static_cast<void*>(modStruc.modBaseAddr) << std::endl;`